# Trakt API using different time for watched status (one hour ahead)

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

I am creating an Android app to manage Trakt account using the Trakt API.

I am using a Retrofit library for accessing this API.

I have a problem where Trakt is adding one hour ahead of the value I am passing.

For example, I am passing a UTC timestamp of:
2019-10-16T19:54Z

I would expect a time of 19:54. Trakt will instead add an hour making it 20:54.
I am using the org.threeten.bp OffSetDateTime library.

I setup the OkHttp class interceptor to check the JSON payload being passed to Trakt API. I am passing correct timestamp (watched_at):
D/OkHttp: {"movies":[{"ids":{"trakt":265470},"watched_at":"2019-10-16T19:54Z"}]}

I have a method (below) which will first display a DatePickerDialog then display TimePickerDialog to capture the Date/Time user selected.

This data is then used to create LocalDateTime object which is then used to build OffsetDateTime for UTC timestamp.

This value is passed to Trakt API:
https://trakt.docs.apiary.io/#reference/sync/add-to-history

Code:

```
        var datePickerFragment =
            DatePickerFragment(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { datePicker, year, month, day ->

                var timePickerFragment =
                    TimePickerFragment(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { timePicker, hourOfDay, minutes ->

                        // Make a LocalDateTime object based on values passed from Android DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog
                        var time = LocalDateTime.of(year, month+1, day, hourOfDay, minutes, 0, 0)

                        // Trakt API requires UTC datetime stamp
                        // https://trakt.docs.apiary.io/#reference/sync/add-to-history
                        var date = OffsetDateTime.of(time, ZoneOffset.UTC)

                        // Create a new SyncMovie instance
                        var syncMovie = SyncMovie().id(MovieIds.trakt(movie!!.ids.trakt))

                        // Set the watched date
                        syncMovie.watched_at = date

                        var checkInRequest = traktApi.sync().addItemsToWatchedHistory(SyncItems().movies(syncMovie))

                        checkInRequest.enqueue(object: Callback<SyncResponse> {
                            override fun onFailure(call: Call<SyncResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to checking movie ${movie!!.title}")
                                Log.e(TAG, t.message)
                                activity?.runOnUiThread {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to checkin movie ${movie!!.title}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                }
                            }

                            override fun onResponse(call: Call<SyncResponse>, response: Response<SyncResponse>) {
                                activity?.runOnUiThread {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Successful checking for movie ${movie!!.title}! You wanted on ${date.format(
                                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm"))}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                }
                            }
                        })


                    })

                timePickerFragment.show(fragmentManager!!, "Time Picker")
            })

        datePickerFragment.show(fragmentManager!!, "Date Picker")
```

I expect I'm missing something straightforward here. I did write a simple Java program to test the results of using the above (Java.time* libraries and not org.threeten*) and couldn't reproduce the problem:

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.of(2019, 10, 16, 18, 35, 0);

OffsetDateTime offsetTime = OffsetDateTime.of(date, ZoneOffset.UTC);

       System.out.println("Time before offset "+date.toString());
       System.out.println("Time post offset "+offsetTime.toString());

       DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH::mm");

       System.out.println("Time formatted before offset - "+date.format(formatter));
       System.out.println("Time formatted post offset - "+offsetTime.format(formatter));
```

The result of above being:

```
Time before offset 2019-10-16T18:35
Time post offset 2019-10-16T18:35Z
Time formatted before offset - 16/10/2019 18::35
Time formatted post offset - 16/10/2019 18::35
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided the best approach to solving this problem is just to take an hour off the time user input, as Trakt will just add another hour anyway:

```
var time = LocalDateTime.of(year, month+1, day, hourOfDay, minutes, 0, 0)

// Trakt time hack, Trakt will automatically add +1 hour for all history syncs, so take one hour to off set this
var timeHack = time.minusHours(1)
var date = OffsetDateTime.of(timeHack, ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

I still don't understand why Trakt adds one hour to the supplied time..